# Android: keep zoom when updated ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, zooming

I created a simple application that will download a `.jpg` image every two seconds from a website and displays it in an `ImageView`.

I added to the `ImageView` the zoom functionality, but each time the image is updated the imageview back to original size. I would like to make sure that by increasing the zoom, the next update of the image, the `ImageView` maintained the dimensions that I set.

Can you please help me?
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compute for the ratio of the image and the current zoom level. You can do this by getting the current size and divide it by the original size. Pretty trivial stuff.
Then when the new image arrives, as soon as you replace the image, change the dimension of the image by the original value times ratio.